# PHP keeps adding data multiple times to csv file

Tags: php, file, csv, append

Im trying to add data to a csv file, however every time i run the php script it will add the data two or three times and that is of course super annoying! Just wondering if anyone has an idea of why this is happening? PHP Code:

```html
$my_file2 = 'TEMP/temp.csv';
$handle = fopen($my_file2, 'a');
$data = "Mobile,".$mobi.",Message,".$message."\n";
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($my_file2);
```

An example of the csv file with double entry: 
 [image]

Comment: is this code your entire PHP script ? is it in a loop ?

Comment: You have added mode `fopen` mode as `a`  so it will append data every time, not overwrite. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function?

```
fputcsv ( resource $handle , array $fields [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape_char = "\\" ]]] ) : int
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why should one try that and how? Keep in mind that explaining your answer helps others to understand it

Comment: Because this is the fist function i've found when i've searched how to save csv in files with php. I've linked also the page to php manual.

Comment: Linking to external sources does not help to solve a problem. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer